# What would be a good approach for developing front-end for ios apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, frontend

I'm new to ios app development. I was told to do the front-end development for an app, which has already been designed by a graphic designer. My question is that what language or tool do I need to learn or use in order to build the front-end for the app. I suppose it's a different thing than web front-end development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two main choices for doing native app development for iOS are Objective-C and Swift.

Apple has made it pretty clear that Swift is the wave of the future. If you plan to develop for iOS long-term then Swift is probably the best choice.

That being said, there are enough legacy frameworks and legacy code written in Objective-C that it's a good idea to learn enough to at least read it.